# Error en un trigger para borrar filas

Tags: mysql, sql, trigger

Tengo el siguiente trigger:

```
    CREATE TRIGGER actualizarConsulta
  AFTER INSERT
  ON ranking
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    DELETE FROM Consulta C
    WHERE C.jugador_id = NEW.player_id;
  END;
```

Cuando lo intento ejecutar me sale el siguiente error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'C   WHERE C.jugador_id = NEW.player_id;   END' at line 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que tienes `BEGIN` `END` alrededor de una declaración no delimitada con un `;`. Sin embargo, si coloca el elemento faltante , deberá introducir un delimitador de metadatos para toda la definición, ya que, si no lo hace, el interior lo romperá.

Por lo tanto, ponga un `;` al final de la declaración `DELETE` y coloque el `DELIMITER` antes de la definición del desencadenante:

En su cláusula `where` cambie `NEW.player_id;` a `OLD.player_id;`

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE
TRIGGER actualizarConsulta
AFTER INSERT ON `ranking`
FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN    
  DELETE FROM Consulta C
  WHERE (C.jugador_id = OLD.player_id); 
 END$$
```

---

O Modifique su Cláusula `Where` agregando `()` y dejando el  `NEW.player_id;` tal como esta:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE
TRIGGER actualizarConsulta
AFTER INSERT ON `ranking`
FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN    
  DELETE FROM Consulta C
  WHERE (C.jugador_id = NEW.player_id); 
 END$$
```

> Me disculpo si cometo algún error, estoy desde el móvil, Saludos!